# SQLite insert from objective c

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite

i am trying to insert into sqlite database using objective c,
the following is my code:

-(void)insertCustomer:(CustomerDetails *)cd{

```
CustomerDetails *cDetails=[[CustomerDetails alloc] initWithIdNumber:cd.idNumber name:cd.name surname:cd.surname];

NSString *name= cDetails.name;
NSString *surname=cDetails.surname;
NSString *idNumber=cDetails.idNumber;


NSString *insertQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DETAILS(Name,Surname,ID_Number) VALUES(?,?,?);"];
sqlite3_stmt *insertStatement;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertQuery UTF8String], 1, &insertStatement, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1,[name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2,[surname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3,[idNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_step(insertStatement);
sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

this is not inserting anything, also when i debug insertStatement seems to be null
i am new to objective c so would appreciate any help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of [`sqllite3_prepare_v2`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) is the number of bytes to read from the SQL statement. Since you are passing 1, one byte is read, in other words you are trying to execute the SQL statement `"I"`. This is not going to work, and `sqllite_prepare_v2` is probably failing  and therefore not assigning anything to `insertStatement` - but since you are not checking the return value for an error code, your code just continues on.

You can pass -1 to have the prepare function read until the null terminator of the UTF8 string. In other words, this should work:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertQuery UTF8String], -1, &insertStatement, NULL);
```

Also, you really should check for errors when using the sqllite API in your code; this will likely avoid or explain other issues in the future. According to the docs:

> On success, the sqlite3_prepare() family of routines return SQLITE_OK;
>   otherwise an error code is returned.

Comment: you were right, insert statement now seems to have a value,however still nothing is inserted in the table, not sure what it could be, i could try do some checks as you said to find out what it is

Comment: is there some sort of commit i need to do?, because when i insert the same data in the same session its giving me an insertion error, which i am thinking is the unique constraint

Comment: Your code _should_ work like that, but maybe I am missing something. Have you tried checking the return codes of `sqlite_step` and `sqlite_finalize` ? Do they tell you anything ?

Comment: step returning 101, finalize returning 0, do thsese codes mean anything? thanks

Comment: 101 is SQLLITE_DONE, so that step should be OK.

Comment: sorry took so long to get back, but ive been busy, decided to get back to this.. prepare returns 0,step 101,finalise 0, close 0....so should be ok...but still no entry in the database :S

Comment: if i insert an entry in the same session with the same id it gives me a unique constraint error, if i insert the same id in a different session, the execution works but still no entry